# I have two arrays roles added and roles deleted, want to merge them and write in this order in perl

Tags: text-processing, perl, uniq

I have another scenario.
My file has the following fields:

```
Username | Roles | Type |date |
abc|admin |added | 01072015
abc|developer |deleted |01072015
abc|deploy |added |01072015
xyz |admin |deleted |01072015
xyz| deploy|deleted|01072015
cdf|deploy|added|01072015
```

Note here, the date is going to be the same day, so no change
now, I want this to be printed as

```
username |roles_added |roles deleted |date
abc |admin,deploy |developer |01072015 
xyz ||admin,deploy |01072015
cdf |deploy||01072015
```

I tried the below approach given, but didn't work out for me. Please guide me.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open(FIL,"report.txt") or die("$!");

my %k=();

while (my $line=<FIL>) {
    my ($user,$roles,$type,$dt)=split(/\|/,$line);

    $k{$user}{$roles}=1;
    $k{$user}{$type}=1;
}

my @names=(sort keys(%k));

foreach my $name (@names) {
    foreach my $value ( (keys(%{$k{$name}})) ){
        print "$value ";
    }
    print "$name\n";
}

print " i am here \n";
while( my ($k, $v) = each %$k ) {
    print "key: $k, value: $v.\n";
}
```

Comment: Ok, Sorry about that, am new to this forum, thanks for the information

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with complex data structures, [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) is your friend. Try adding `use Data::Dumper` to your code and then `print Dumper \%k` just after you've finished building your `%k` hash. You'll see something like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'xyz' => {
                     ' deploy' => 1,
                     'deleted' => 1
                   },
          'Username ' => {
                           ' Type ' => 1,
                           ' Roles ' => 1
                         },
          'xyz ' => {
                      'deleted ' => 1,
                      'admin ' => 1
                    },
          'cdf' => {
                     'deploy' => 1,
                     'added' => 1
                   },
          'abc' => {
                     'deleted ' => 1,
                     'deploy ' => 1,
                     'developer ' => 1,
                     'added ' => 1,
                     'admin ' => 1
                   }
        };
```

See how the keys in the sub-hashes are names after two types of things. Half of them are the role names and half of them are "added" or "deleted". It's going to be really hard to get anything useful out of that data structure, so let's try something different.

Where you had:

```
$k{$user}{$roles}=1;
$k{$user}{$type}=1;
```

Try this instead:

```
push @{$k{$user}{type}}, $role;
```

Now our data structure looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'xyz' => {
                     'deleted' => [
                                    ' deploy'
                                  ]
                   },
          'xyz ' => {
                      'deleted ' => [
                                      'admin '
                                    ]
                    },
          'cdf' => {
                     'added' => [
                                  'deploy'
                                ]
                   },
          'abc' => {
                     'deleted ' => [
                                     'developer '
                                   ],
                     'added ' => [
                                   'admin ',
                                   'deploy '
                                 ]
                   }
        };
```

I think you can see that it's far easier to get the information you want out of this data structure. It's basically:

```
foreach (@names) {
   print join ',', @{$k{$_}{added}};
   print join ',', @{$k{$_}{deleted}};
}
```

You'll need to change the code a little to get exactly what you want.

Oh, and please get into the habit of adding `use strict` and `use warnings` to all of your code. They would have shown you why the debugging output at the end of your original code wasn't working.

**Update:** I threw together a complete solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %k;

<>; # Skip header

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my ($user, $roles, $type, $dt) = split(/\s*\|\s*/);

  push @{$k{$user}{$type}}, $roles;
  $k{$user}{date} = $dt;
}

say 'username |roles_added |roles deleted |date';

foreach my $name (sort keys %k) {
  say "$name |",
      join(',',@{$k{$name}{added} || []}), ' |',
      join(',',@{$k{$name}{deleted} || []}), ' |',
      $k{$name}{date};
}
```

You need to pass it the name of the input file as a command line argument.

Comment: The join fails when there are no entries for "added" or "deleted" type. I tried the code like foreach ( @names) {
   print join ',', @{$k{$_}{Added}} if ( @{$k{$_}{Added}} ne '');
   print "\n";
   print join ',', @{$k{$_}{Deleted}} if ( @{$k{$_}{Deleted}} ne '');
   print "\n";
}
But no luck.The error i am getting is _italic_Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at report3.pl line 30, <FIL> line 23.

Comment: As I said - "You'll need to change the code a little to get exactly what you want" :-)

Comment: Can you please help me how to join the hash values without undefined array reference error. I am stuck here and looking for your help.

Comment: the values are `$VAR1 = {
          'abc' => {
                                      'Deleted' => [
                                                     '131~Prod Deploy'
                                                   ]
                                    },
          'bca' => {
                                         'Deleted' => [
                                                        '321~QA Deploy'
                                                      ]
                                       },

Comment: `print exists $k{$_}{added} ? join(',', @{$k{$_}{added}}) : '';`